# Why is the output of the two given cout statements different in the given cpp code

Tags: c++, recursion

The below is a code to find number of words in a given sentence using recursion.

It seems that the two given "cout" statements result in different outputs and i cannot seem to understand the reason why?

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;

int count_end(char *a, int start, int ctr) {

  if (a[start] == '.') {
    cout << ctr << "\n";
    return ctr;
  }

  else if (a[start] == ' ' && a[start - 1] != ' ') {
    ctr++;
  }

  start = count_end(a, start + 1, ctr);
  return ctr;
}

int main() {

  char sentence[1000];
  cin.getline(sentence, 1000);

  int x;
  x = count_end(sentence, 1, 1);
  cout << "is count" << x << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

I tried writing cout statements in later part of codes to judge the control flow. It seems the control flow is fine. I know of different ways to implement the same thing which give the correct output but I wonder why this particular method doesn't work.

Comment: it could be that when you call `count_end` recursively, you aren't actually returning the value it returns

Comment: Well, for one thing, your recursion makes this difficult to understand. Programming languages have invented loops a long time ago -- use them. Also, I suspect that when you do the recursive call to `count_end`, you wanted to assign the return value to `ctr`?

Comment: Recommendation: Hardcode an input. Don't make people guess at what input they should use while debugging because they'll probably find different bugs.

Comment: put recursion aside for a moment, suppose this line `start = count_end(a, start + 1, ctr);` wasnt there. The the function when called from `main` does return the value of `ctr`. Now consider what effect that line has on the valuie of `ctr`. It has none. You recurse but effectively there is no recursion.

Comment: which two couts would you expect to result in the same output and why?

Comment: Your algorithm requires that a sentence end with a period, but your program does nothing to enforce that. What happens if the user forgets to type a period? In that case, you should probably just add a period at the end of the sentence, before starting the recursion..

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your problem is the following: You never return the number of words to the initial function call. The initial function call returns the initial ctr value that was passed to it, because you never set it to a different value. Therefore you need to implement the function like this:

```
int count_end(char *a, int start, int ctr) {

  if (a[start] == '.') {
    cout << ctr << "\n";
    return ctr;
  }

  else if (a[start] == ' ' && a[start - 1] != ' ') {
    ctr++;
  }

  return count_end(a, start + 1, ctr);
}
```

---

To sum it up:

You must return the value from the inner function to the function that called it before, instead of returning the initial ctr value.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by @Christian Stieber identifies the immediate problem:

> When you do the recursive call to `count_end`, you wanted to assign the return value to `ctr`.

```cpp
//start = count_end(a, start + 1, ctr);  // Wrong!

ctr = count_end(a, start + 1, ctr);      // Right.
```

With this fix, the two `cout` expressions display the same value. For the trial run below, I entered a famous quotation by Mahatma Gandhi.

```
An ounce of patience is worth more than a tonne of preaching.
12
is count12
```

You can clean up the output by by removing `cout` from function `count_end`, and rewording the message.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;

int count_end(char* a, int start, int ctr) {

    if (a[start] == '.') {
        //cout << ctr << "\n";                   // Delete this.
        return ctr;
    }

    else if (a[start] == ' ' && a[start - 1] != ' ') {
        ctr++;
    }

    //start = count_end(a, start + 1, ctr);      // Wrong!
    ctr = count_end(a, start + 1, ctr);          // Right.
    return ctr;
}

int main() {

    char sentence[1000];
    cout
        << "WORD COUNTER\n\n"
        << "Enter some text: ";
    cin.getline(sentence, 1000);
    cout << '\n';

    int x;
    x = count_end(sentence, 1, 1);
    cout << "Word count: " << x << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

Output:

```
WORD COUNTER

Enter some text: An ounce of patience is worth more than a tonne of preaching.

Word count: 12
```

##### What about sentences that do not end with a period?

The algorithm used by this program requires that a sentence end with a period. In case none is found, it will overrun the string, and possibly, the buffer, in a fruitless effort to find one.

```
WORD COUNTER

Enter some text: An ounce of patience is worth more than a tonne of preaching

Word count: 14
```

Other times, it will misread an ellipsis (`...`), and declare the end of a sentence, when, in fact, it is still in the middle.

```
WORD COUNTER

Enter some text: It will misread an ellipsis (`...`), and declare the end of a sentence.

Word count: 6
```

A period alone, without any other characters, led to this:

```
WORD COUNTER

Enter some text: .

Word count: 4
```

##### Empty strings, trailing whitespace, and off-by-one errors

The limiting case of the *I-forgot-the-period* comes when you forget the whole sentence! For this run, I just pressed Enter, without entering anything.

```
WORD COUNTER

Enter some text:

Word count: 3
```

A one-word entry, followed by a space, led to this output:

```
WORD COUNTER

Enter some text: one

Word count: 5
```

And a simple space alone gave me this:

```
WORD COUNTER

Enter some text:

Word count: 3
```

##### Stop recursion when the null character is found

It is obvious, by now, that recursion should stop when the null character (`'\0'`) is found.

```cpp
// Recursion stops at the end of the string.
if (a[start] == '\0') {
    return ctr;
}
```

This fixes many of the issues above, but won't solve the problem of the empty string or trailing spaces.

##### Detecting the end of a word

The end of a word occurs when a non-whitespace character is followed by either whitespace, or the null character, which marks the end of the C-string. The program in the OP, fails to check the latter case.

```cpp
// ...
else if (a[start] != ' '                                 // non-whitespace
    && (a[start + 1] == '\0' || a[start + 1] == ' ')) {  // followed by null or whitespace
    ctr++;
}
```

Because this test looks *forward* in the string, rather than *backward*, as does the test in the OP, recursion can start properly in function `main`, with both position and word count set to zero. That will prevent a couple of *off-by-one* errors from occurring.

It is okay to look forward, because the test to detect the end of a word does not occur until after it has been determined that `a[start]` is not the terminating null character. Examining the character at `a[start + 1]` will not overrun the string.

The following two helper functions are used to extend this test to any whitespace character.

```cpp
bool is_space(unsigned char const c) {
    // Note: Per CppReference, `std::isspace` should be called with 
    // an unsigned argument.
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace
    return std::isspace(c);
}

bool is_null_or_space(unsigned char const c) {
    return !c || std::isspace(c);
}
```

This leads to:

```cpp
// Count word endings.
// The end of a word occurs when a non-whitespace character 
// is followed by either whitespace, or the null character,
// which marks the end of the C-string.
if (!is_space(a[start]) && is_null_or_space(a[start + 1])) {
    ++ctr;
}
```

##### Start recursion with position and count both zero

This can be accomplished by changing one line in function `main`:

```cpp
// from function `main`
x = count_end(sentence, 0, 0);
```

I prefer, however, to change the name of function `count_end` to the more expressive `count_word_endings`. At the same time, I am going to provide a couple of default arguments to get the recursion started:

```cpp
int count_word_endings(
    char* a,         // null-terminated C-string
    int start = 0,   // start search at `a[start]`
    int ctr = 0)     // word counter
{
    // ...
}
```

##### The complete program

The following program fixes the issues described above.

Recursion starts with the call to `count_word_endings(text)` in function `main`.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

bool is_space(unsigned char const c) {
    // Note: Per CppReference, `std::isspace` should be called with 
    // an unsigned argument.
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace
    return std::isspace(c);
}

bool is_null_or_space(unsigned char const c) {
    return !c || std::isspace(c);
}

int count_word_endings(
    char* a,         // null-terminated C-string
    int start = 0,   // start search at `a[start]`
    int ctr = 0)     // word counter
{
    // Recursion stops at the end of the string.
    if (a[start] == '\0') {
        return ctr;
    }
    
    // Count word endings.
    // The end of a word occurs when a non-whitespace character 
    // is followed by either whitespace, or the null character,
    // which marks the end of the C-string.
    if (!is_space(a[start]) && is_null_or_space(a[start + 1])) {
        ++ctr;
    }

    // Continue recursion, starting at the next character.
    return count_word_endings(a, start + 1, ctr);
}

int main() {
    enum : std::size_t { BUFFER_SIZE = 1000 };
    char text[BUFFER_SIZE];
    std::cout
        << "WORD COUNTER\n\n"
        << "Enter some text: ";
    std::cin.getline(text, BUFFER_SIZE);
    std::cout << "\nWord count: " << count_word_endings(text) << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```